# Java multiple Images Uploader

Tags: java, image, uploader

I have this new requirement to develop a software which is a large scale image up loader in a web application. I was able to do the same using swing contains several feature like drag and drop, progress bar, remove file / files , modify, limit file size, verify file information, timer, verify at run time ..and its a very powerful tool which uploads images.

I would like to do the same in web based app, like user selects 200 images process it and click upload and it should start uploading, like to know any feasible frameworks or any API's which help me do this faster and achieve the same kind of functionality. Please point me in correct direction.

-PD

Answer (score 1):

You can do upload apps, but not fancy stuff like drag and drop with run of the mill HTML.  HTML5 on google chrome maybe, but I doubt you want code that only works on chrome.

Have you looked into turning your image uploader app into a java applet? Applets generally have a bad rep, but this is one of the very (in my opinion) valid uses of one...

Answer (score 1):

Either turn your uploader into an [applet](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/applet/) or use a 3rd party image upload applet, such as [JumpLoader](http://www.jumploader.com/). You then just embed this applet in your webpage. Turning your uploader into an applet should actually be a piece of cake since you've the UI apparently already ready. You can make use of [deployJava.js](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) script to reliably deploy an applet.